# Issues when building C++ using CMake with Intel oneApi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, intel-oneapi

I my library I use boost's [float128](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html) wrapper therefore changing the compiler is not an option.

Following [Intel's developer guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-dpcpp-cpp-compiler-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-setup/use-the-command-line/use-cmake-with-the-compiler.html) I added `find_package(IntelDPCPP REQUIRED)` to my `CMakeLists.txt` and ran `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icx -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icx -GNinja` on the VS 2022 terminal. I get the following error message

```
 Found package configuration file:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/compiler/latest/windows/IntelDPCPP/IntelDPCPPConfig.cmake

  but it set IntelDPCPP_FOUND to FALSE so package "IntelDPCPP" is considered
  to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Unsupported compiler family and compiler icx!!
```

Anyone with a similar issue that can help out?

EDIT: as suggested by @Botje here the output information relevant to this case

```
IntelDPCPPConfig.cmake(84): string(COMPARE EQUAL ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} nocmplr )
IntelDPCPPConfig.cmake(85): if(nocmplr)
IntelDPCPPConfig.cmake(93): if(NOT x${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL xClang AND NOT x${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL xIntelLLVM )
IntelDPCPPConfig.cmake(95): set(IntelDPCPP_FOUND False )
```

Comment: Suggest you run CMake with `--trace` and/or read the IntelDPCPPConfig.cmake file to figure out why it fails.

Comment: Thanks @Botje I edited the question accordingly

Comment: "nocmplr" sounds like the config disagrees with your input and/or environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, it will be fixed in the OneAPI 2023.1 release.
You can try reversing the order of find_package and project or removing find_package(IntelDPCPP REQUIRED) in CMakeLists.txt. Because CMake identifies and sets up all the compiler-related variables when the project() is called.
Also, you can set the compiler option for the DPC++ compiler in CMakeLists.txt using the below command.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER dpcpp)
```